# Mobile always going to recovery

Tags: recovery-mode

I tried to update my mobile (who had cenymotion based android) using the update feature. And now it is always going to recovery (TeamWin 2.8.6.1) mode even if I switch it on only with the power button.

I tried with factory reset, swipe everything and install the OS with adb and nothing seems to work.

How can I make to go to the OS instead of the recovery mode?

Comment: You need to flash the whole phone. But simply flashing the boot partition may solve the issue, since you haven't specified what device you have, I can't tell more.